# Is there an Android equivalent to ASP.NET's DoEvents()?

Tags: android, asp.net

I have an Android app where I would like to display a "Processing..." message at the start of quite a bit of heavy duty number crunching, then display "Finished" when the processing is completed.  I try something like this:

```
TextView T = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TheStatusView);
T.setText("Running");
T.invalidate();
// lots of number crunching
T.setText("Completed");
```

As some of you might have guessed by now, the "Running" message never appears, since the application is too busy with the number crunching to get around to redrawing the TextView.

In ASP.NET, I would do something like:

```
T.Text = "Running";
T.Refresh();
Application.DoEvents();
```

and the text would be refreshed.
Is there an equivalent in Android, or am I pretty much stuck?

Comment: Look into [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Don't run your long-running code on UI thread or Android will kill it.

Comment: Changes to views don't happen until you draw, which doesn't happen until you return from whatever function Android called so it can call the appropriate onDraw functions.  So to do something like this you have to use another thread (like AsyncTask) or provide some other way of breaking up the setup from the calculations like a post to a handler.  AsyncTasks are preferred as holding up the UI thread is a bad experience and may crash you.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are playing at home and looking to do the same thing, here's what I did:

```
TextView T = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        T.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                T.setText("Processing Part 1");
            }
            });
            DoTheHardcoreProcessing_Part1();
            T.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    T.setText("Processing Part 2");
                }
            });
            DoTheHardcoreProcessing_Part2();
            T.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    T.setText("Finished");
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

This will, in order:

(1) display "Processing Part 1"

(2) execute the code in DoTheHardcoreProcessing_Part1()

(3) display "Processing Part 2"

(4) execute the code in DoTheHardcoreProcessing_Part2()

(5) display "Finished"